# How do I make inputAccessoryView stay on screen when using drag to dismiss?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, inputaccessoryview

I know that the view controller must be firstResponder in order for the inputAccessory to stay at the bottom. I am using a custom inputView / keyboard. I can manually dismiss it with a done button by removing the inputView but not resigning first responder. However when I enable the interactive drag to dismiss on my scrollview, the code automatically resigns first responder. So how can I use the interactive drag to dismiss and yet keep my viewcontroller as first responder? Anyone done this before? I thought maybe it is not possible and that I may need to make my own interactive drag to dismiss using a gesture recognizer.

More info: 
I have a button that swaps between standard keyboard and my custom one. I have seen dismissing these cause 2 keyboard did dismiss notifications. I thought I could become firstResponder in the keyboardDidHide method but this didn't work well since I couldn't tell the difference between when I manually dismissed the keyboard and when the interactive drag does it. This matters because I don't need to reload the input view or become first responder when I manually dismiss because I took care of it already.

Any suggestions would be amazing. I am trying to use inputView and inputAccessoryView on the UIViewController level.

Comment: inputAccessoryView is a get only prop on UIViewController. How did you manage to set it?

Answer (score 5):

Well after a day of pulling my hair, I have an answer.

Using the `canResignFirstResponder` of my viewcontroller did the trick. In `viewWillAppear` I set a `BOOL responderOverride = YES;`

In `viewWillDisappear` I call

`responderOverride = NO; 
[self resignFirstResponder];`

When the interactive drag on the scrollview tries to resignFirstResponder, `canResignFirstResponder` returns no which prevents my viewcontroller from resigning and keeps my input accessory retained and sitting at the bottom of the screen.

There is a lot of other code with reloading input views but since the real question was how to force a controller to stay first responder so we don't lose our input accessory view, then this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder : Bool {
     get {
           retrun true
      }
}
```

This works for me