# How to hide only keyboard not inputAccessoryView in Swift

Tags: swift, swift5

I have a textField at the bottom of screen. So I use inputAccessoryView with text field. Everything is correctly working, but when i hiding keyboard my inputAccessoryView is also hiding. I don't want to hide my inputAccessoryView (the textField at bottom):

```
textfields.inputAccessoryView = backgroundViews
```

For hiding textField:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

[image]

After using inputAccessoryView view included with textfield comes on top of the keyboard, but when I click on the return button to hide the keyboard. It hides both keyboard and view both. I want to hide only keyboard not the view.The view should be fixed to previous position.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Could you share some photos of what is happening with you?

Comment: @TDMNS check it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make inputAccessoryView stay on screen when using drag to dismiss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633079/how-do-i-make-inputaccessoryview-stay-on-screen-when-using-drag-to-dismiss)